# Open Publisher files in a folder and save as Word documents

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word, ms-publisher

I need to open a large amount of documents that are currently saved in Publisher (2003, 2007, and 2010) and convert them to Word documents. These are simple one page text documents but I have about 1,000 of them to convert. Here is the code I have:

```
Public Sub Pub_To_Word()

Dim FS As New FileSystemObject
Dim pubApp As Publisher.Application
' Reference Library pointing to:
' Microsoft Scripting Runtime
' Microsoft Word 14.0 Object Library
Dim FSfolder As Folder
Dim MyFile As File
Dim mydoc As Document
Dim sFolderPath As String
Dim Table As Table


sFolderPath = "I:\My Documents\Publisher Test"
Set FSfolder = FS.GetFolder(sFolderPath)

For Each MyFile In FSfolder.Files

           Set mydoc = pubApp.Open(MyFile)
               Application.DisplayAlerts = False
               mydoc.SaveAs Filename:MyFile & ".docx", FileFormat:=wdFormatXMLDocument
               mydoc.Close savechanges:=True
           pubApp.DisplayAlerts = True

      End If

     Next

    End
End Sub
```

The code debugs at

```
 FileFormat:=wdFormatXMLDocument
```

I can't seem to get past this point.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you're doing it in Excel, but:

- Looks like you're missing colon in `Filename:MyFile & ".docx"`.
- These are the valid file formats for Document.SaveAs: https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff940508.aspx. I guess you might have to save as RTF (pbFileRTF = 6) or HTML and convert that to .docx via Word's interop. This, admittedly deprecated, article points in that direction as well: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/302939. (Maybe you'll have to use the number 6 instead of the defined constant since you're doing this in Excel)

Edit:
wdFormatXMLDocument might not be defined since you run the macro from Publisher, so the easiest would be to replace it by 12